# Data Annotations do not work in Domain Class in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I am writing an ASP.NET MVC application. There are two solutions, Sportsstore.Domain and Sportsstore.WebUI. I have a *Product* class as mentioned below:

```
namespace SportsStore.Domain.Entities
{
 public class Product
 {
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int ProductId {get;set;}
    public string ProductName {get;set;}

    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string ProductDescription {get;set;}
    public decimal ProductPrice {get;set;}
    public string ProductCategory { get; set; }
 }
}
```

As you can see, *ProductId* depicted as hidden and *ProductDescription* depicted as Multilinetext. I want to edit the content of any Product, so details exist below :

Content of edit function of related controller:

```
    public ViewResult Edit(int? PRODUCT_ID)
    {
        try
        {
            //Connecting to the Entity Framework
            using (ProductContext pr = new ProductContext())
            {
                PRODUCT product = pr.ProductsList.FirstOrDefault(p => p.PRODUCT_ID == PRODUCT_ID);

                if (product != null)
                {
                    return View(product);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("Product Id boş geliyor.");

                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
            return View();
        }            

    }
```

Here is the Edit.cshtml:

```
@model SportsStore.Domain.PRODUCT

@{
     ViewBag.Title = "Admin: Edit " + @Model.PRODUCT_NAME;
     Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml";
 }

  <h1>Edit @Model.PRODUCT_NAME</h1>
  @using (Html.BeginForm())
  {
       @Html.EditorForModel()
       <input type="submit" value="Save" />
       @Html.ActionLink("Cancel and return to List", "Index")
  }
```

The problem is that whenever I run the code, edit page comes, however the annotations does not work, in a word, `ProductId` is editable. What is the point? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I immediately see the solution. The *Product* class here is the Domain's class. However, I gave the *PRODUCT* class that comes directly from Entity Framework. In order to make the code run, I shall map the *Product* class in Domain and the *PRODUCT* class in the Entity Framework.